# Trying to delete node from a particular position . But I can only delete when in only input position 1 in the terminal

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list, function-definition

**after running the code ,the program ask the position from where you want to delete a node . I ran the code but it only work when I input postion 1 .For other position like 2,3,4 it does not work .**

here i want to insert number at end of a node :

```
void Insert(int data)
{
    struct node* temp1;
    temp1=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp1->data=data;
    temp1->next=NULL;

    if (head==NULL){
        temp1->next=head;
        head=temp1;
    }
    else{
        struct node* temp2;
        temp2=head;
        while(temp2->next!=NULL)
        {
            temp2=temp2->next;
        }

        temp2->next=temp1;
    }
}
```

Print function:

```
void Print()
{
    struct node*temp99;
    temp99=head;
    while(temp99!=NULL){
        printf(" %d",temp99->data);
        temp99=temp99->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Delete function:

```
void Delete(int n)
{
    struct node* temp33;
    temp33=head;

    if (n==1)
    {
        head=temp33->next;
        free(temp33);
    }
    else{
        int i;
        for (i=0;i<n-2;i++)
        {
            temp33=temp33->next;
        }
        struct node* temp44;
        temp44=temp33->next;

        temp44->next=temp33->next;

        free(temp44);
    }
}
```

Comment: Pick **a** (one) language. Then strongly consider what `temp44 = temp33->next; temp44->next = temp33->next; free(temp44)` is actually doing.

Comment: Recommendation: Whichever you select, both C and C++ are zero-based languages, so you might want to retain this semantics for your list as well, anything else might lead to a nice surprise for a user of your *list*. For a user of your *programme* you still might present a one-based interface – then you should do the necessary translation between index systems immediately after input and immediately before output – and anywhere else prefer the system of the language (i.e. zero-based).

Comment: An fyi, this is a *lot* easier with a pointer-to-pointer walking the list. As a bonus it removes the special-case requirement for the head pointer. [see here](https://pastebin.com/N3Y2PN7S).

Comment: As you don't need `n` any more anyway: A bit simpler the loop is `for(/*--n*/; n != 0; --n)` – uncomment first decrement if you don't follow my advice of zero-based indices... If you want the counter variable `i` anyway then give it a scope not larger than needed, i.e. loop only: `for(int i = 0; ...)`.

Comment: @WhozCraig Understanding the double pointer might not be too easy for a beginner either, still I like that approach for its simplicity – in a high performance scenario double indirection might be a disadvantage, though. Well, in such case an array based approach might be preferrable anyway, but still...

Comment: Your design suffers from a big disadvantage: As you rely on globals you only ever can create at most one single list (actually one always exists...). Better design is providing the head node explicitly to your functions, then you can define multiple such lists, even locally e.g. within `main`. Appending new nodes gets much more efficient if you maintain a separate `tail` pointer and you might want to manage the number of nodes contained in the list as well. If you do so, then create yet another struct `list` with all that data and pass instances of as pointers to your functions.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `temp44->next=temp33->next;` with `temp33->next=temp44->next;`.

And give better names to your variables.

Answer (score 1):

For starters indices shall start from 0. Secondly the function parameter shall have an unsigned integer type as for example `size_t`.

When n is not equal to 1 these manipulations with pointers

```
    struct node* temp44;
    temp44=temp33->next;

    temp44->next=temp33->next;

    free(temp44);
```

do not make a sense. For example data member `next` of the pointer `temp33` is not changed.

And moreover this for loop

```
    for (i=0;i<n-2;i++)
    {
        temp33=temp33->next;
    }
```

can invoke undefined behavior because there is no check whether `temp33` is not equal to `NULL`.

Even this code snippet

```
if (n==1)
{
    head=temp33->next;
    free(temp33);
}
```

can invoke undefined behavior when the list is empty that is when `head` is equal to `NULL`.

The function can be defined the following way

```
int Delete( size_t n ) 
{
    struct node **current = &head;

    while ( *current != NULL && n )
    {
        current = &( *current )->next;
        --n;
    }

    int success = *current != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        struct node *node_to_delete = *current;
        *current = ( *current )->next;
        free( node_to_delete );
    }

    return success;
}
```

Comment: @DaVinciN Such opportunity for undefined behaviour *can* be acceptable in some circumstances, though, in favour of a performance gain. Conditions for are: 1. The UB being well documented occurring on trying to delete an inexistent node. 2. Offering the user a way to avoid the UB by other means, which would usually mean in given case providing a way to retrieve the number of elements in the list (which doesn't seem exist for now, though).